# How to simulate the back button through enzyme or jest with react-native

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am unable to mock the hardware back button by using enzyme/jest with react-native code. And also mentioned that I am new to the Enzyme/Jest with react-native

I followed the following link and tried to implement. Unfortunately, I am unable to do that.

[How to simulate android back button in react-native test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952284/how-to-simulate-android-back-button-in-react-native-test)

Sample.js,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  BackHandler,
  BackAndroid
} from "react-native";

  componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonPress);
  }

  handleBackButtonPress = () => {
    return true;
  };
```

sample.test.js,

```
import 'react-native';
import React from "react";
import  mockPressBack  from 'react-native';

jest.mock('BackHandler', () => {
    return {
        addEventListener: mockPressBack
    };
});

describe('sample verifies', ()=>{
      test('back button press', ()=> {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Sample />);
    const sampleData = wrapper.instance();
    sampleData.componentWillMount(); 
    });
});
```

Actual Result:
TypeError: _reactNative.BackHandler.addEventListener is not a function

Expected Result:
It runs successfully.

I am struck here. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's recommended for unit-tests mocking most if not all dependencies. The tiny thing is [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules) works for whole module - so it needs [additional efforts](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks) if you need to mock certain `export` but leave another one live.

You just need to mock `BackHandler` component. But if you write something like

```
jest.mock('react-native');
// ...
```

You will get an error saying

> BackHandler.addEventListener is not a function

That's because base `jest.mock()` replaces each export with `jest.fn()` mock function. But `BackHandler` is not a function initially, it's an object.

So you need to mock module manually providing value for `BackHandler`:

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'; // it's needed to direct access mocked version

jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  BackHandler: { 
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
  }
});

describe('Sample', () => { 
  it('binds to BackHandler on mount and clean up on destroy', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Sample />);
    expect(BackHandler.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hardwareBackPress');
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(BackHandler.removeEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hardwareBackPress');
  });
```

To simulate `hardwareBackPress` I'd suggest few different ways:

1. to mock `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` with actual storing callback provided(this approach is clear, but needs additional code - and also it needs to cleaning up between test cases)

   ```
   const callbacks = {};
   function helperTriggerListeners(eventName, event) { 
       (callbacks[eventName] || []).forEach(callback => callback(event));
   }

   jest.mock('react-native', () => {
     BackHandler: { 
       addEventListener: jest.fn().mockImplementation((eventName, callback) => {
         callbacks[eventName] = callbacks[eventName] || [];
         callbacks[eventName].psuh(callback);
       }),
       removeEventListener: jest.fn().mockImplementation((eventName, callback) => {
         const indexOf = (callbacks[eventName] || []).indexOf(callback);
         if (indexOf != -1) {
           callbacks[eventName] = callbacks[eventName].splice(indexOf, 1);
         }
       }),
     }
   });

   beforeEach(() => {
       // really important to ensure it's clean from data made in older runs
       callbacks = {};
       BackHandler.addEventListener.mockClear();
       BackHandler.removeEventListener.mockClear();
   });

   it('...', () => {
    helperTriggerListeners('hardwareBackPress', { /* mocked event if required */});
    expect(someOtherMockedService.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
   ```
2. take callback right from `addEventListener` mock log:

   ```
   beforeEach(() => {
       // really important otherwise you may call callbacks for component already unmounted 
       BackHandler.addEventListener.mockClear();
       BackHandler.removeEventListener.mockClear();
   });

   it('reacts on hardwareBackPress', () => {
     const wrapper = shallow(<Sample />);
     BackHandler.addEventListener.mock.calls.forEach(oneCall => {
       if (oneCall[0] === 'hardwareBackPress') oneCall[1]({ /*mocked Event object*/ });
     })
     expect(someOtherMockedService.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
   ```

Comment: The way you mock back handler from react-native it does not make sense and not work. Even I fix by replacing `:` to `=` it said `backhandler is read only`. I don't know why you get voted anyway.

Comment: @Marfin.F what do you mean "does not make sense"? [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter) completely mock given file or module, so there cannot be error such a "is read only".

Comment: btw if you think someone's answer is useless or misleading, you can also downvote it

Answer (score 1):

React-native already have mock for this and you can add this to your project if it somehow didn't added:

```
//__mocks__/globalMock.ts

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Utilities/BackHandler', () => {
  return jest.requireActual(
    'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/__mocks__/BackHandler.js',
  );
});
```

```
//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    ....
    'setupFilesAfterEnv': [
        '<rootDir>/__mocks__/globalMock.ts',
    ],
};
```

```
// amazing test

  it('BackHandler', () => {
    const onClose = jest.fn();
    render(<SomeComp onClose={onClose} />);
    // look into node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/__mocks__/BackHandler.js
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    BackHandler.mockPressBack();

    expect(onClose).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```